# Rename a Plone user account

Tags: plone

Is it possible to rename the id of a Plone user?

Sometimes people have good reasons to change their user name, e.g. because of marriage. In the profile the name information can be changed easily, but the user id is written in some places, and the user name (which might not match the current name of the person anymore) can irritate group members.

I found [this basic information about member manipulation](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/members/member_basics.html), but there is nothing said about whether or not this would be at all supported.

Comment: Depending on how complex your permission assignments are, you might consider using [plone.app.changeownership](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.changeownership) to transfer ownership to a new user with the desired user id.

Comment: Yes, replacing the old user by a new one (who takes over all contents of the now-obsolete user) is definitely an option; I'll look into this. It would be useful to preserve the existing password (but perhaps impossible), and to find the new user when searching for the old id.

Answer (score 7):

The user manager plugin stores 3 attributes, the `User ID`, the `login name` and the `password`.

`login name` and `password` can be changed, the `User ID` is immutable.

The `Login ID` is only for internal usage, in your case you can go to `ZMI -> acl_users > source_users > {SELECT USER}` and change the `login name`.

You need to do it thru the ZMI, afaik there's no Plone UI for this purpose.

**Update**

---

According to the discussion I guess the wish of renaming a plone user should solve a problem I also know very well.
Example use-cases:

- An employment gets replaced by another one.
- Marriage, different userid for example als in AD/LDAP environment.
- The userid is commonly used, like windows auth name, or similiar and thus needs to be changed.

This is how I usually solve this problem:

1. Create new user with the new ID
2. Copy all local roles from the old to the new user ([Code example](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.permissionmanager/blob/master/ftw/permissionmanager/browser/copy_permissions.py#L82))
3. Remove all permission of the old user ([Code Example](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.permissionmanager/blob/master/ftw/permissionmanager/browser/remove_permissions.py#L76))
4. Copy group membership (I got no script for this purpose since Plone has a good  group membership form).
5. Change Ownershipt with plone.app.changeownership (This includes the Creators field).

The linked code is a package we usually install to solve exact the mentioned problems. If Plone would have a feature "Rename UserID" it would be likely that it would proceed those 4 steps.

---

Comment: Ok, so I can change the `login name`; in this case I'll have a user object with a `login name` which is different from the user id.
Normally both are identical, and I'm note quite sure we have considered the case that they might not be. Quite possibly we'll run into problems ...

Comment: Yes and it's not a problem, or I do not remember  a case where this leads to a problem. AFAIK you have the option in plone to switch between email as login and login name as login. If you do so, changing the login should also work in your case.

Comment: It may very well not lead to any problems, but the old user id is still the one which is used in lists etc., so it doesn't help much, either. And if email addresses were not used for login from the beginning, it is perfectly possible for several accounts to share a common email address - a valid reason for this would be to have a non-privileged user for everyday work, and another one for administrative tasks.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to list user ids on purpose, as fallback it's probably OK. If possible show the Fullname. OK I guess there is not a technical problem it's more a bad feeling in your case. I'll update my answer with some hints to scripts, which may fit your needs. Concerning  email as login: Of course that's why you can choose between 2 login options in Plone.

Comment: I don't understand your item `4.`, "... since Plone has I OK group membership form". Of course all group memberships of the old user must be updated to use the new id; or would this be done by one of the other steps?